# How can I restrict my server to start only on specified port?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a server which listens on certain port (fixed).

Now if that port is not available, it starts on any random port. I don't want this.

How can I make sure that if the specified port is not available, my service should not start?

```
int fd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
int32_t const opt = 1;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(61014);
::bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
::listen(fd, 5);
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Edit the code into your question, don't post code into comments, it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As showed above your code won't compile. But I think you want to achieve something like the code below:
You have to check if the bind() call fails. If so than this would mean that this port is already in use. It can also happen that you already own a port, so it is recommended to use the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag.

```
if( bind(fd_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    //print the error message
    perror("Bind failed.");
    return 1;
}
```